# What's the significance of this Google Apps error code '0x8004010B'?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, google-workspace, pst, google-sync

There seems to be a lack of good information around this particular Google Apps error code.

Has anyone found common environmental information that causes this error? Any kind of solution?

Uninstalling/re-installing Google Sync doesn't seem to do anything, I've run Outlook's executable that scans/fixes the PST file etc.

> Task 'Google Apps - ::user email
>   address:: - Sending' reported error
>   (0x8004010B) : 'Unknown Error
>   0x8004010B'

I found a listing of error codes for the Gdata API but nothing for these types of 'unknown' error codes.

Does Google have available a list of common 'unknown' error codes/messages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe I've got it figured out. The problem are emails not downloading from Google to Outlook. This can be caused by a number of things including large emails not downloading (slow connection), corrupt file attachments, improperly formed mail message, etc.

Because there is still communication going on between Outlook and Google, if you manually hit Send/Receive in Outlook it throws the MAPI_E_BUSY error, saying 'Hang on, I'm still communicating with them, you'll have to wait'.

Deleting the trouble-some messages via the Google Apps web mail interface, and then restarting Outlook seems to fix the problem.

Research:

First, I found a helpful tool and information for diagnosing these Outlook errors.

Microsoft provides [Microsoft Exchange Server Error Code Look-up](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=985).

A quick search returned with the following information:

> for hex 0x8004010b / decimal
> -2147221237 :
>
> ecBusy ec.h
>
> MAPI_E_BUSY mapicode.h

Looking up 'MAPI_E_BUSY' I got the following description, found [here](http://www.mailrules.com/support/help/864.htm):

> Another operation is in progress; it should be allowed to complete, or it should be stopped, before this operation should be initiated.

Also, for reference, here's a [List of Extended MAPI numeric result codes](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/238119), including 0x8004010b

Answer (score 2):

Here is [Google apps error codes](http://code.google.com/googleapps/domain/gdata_provisioning_api_v2.0_reference.html#GDATA_error_codes).  I think that may be a MS outlook error, see [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/814441/en-us).

Actually, it is definitely a MS outlook error.  See [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/867623).

Comment: Already saw the first two, the third looks promising, though, odd because the error message is generated as a result of modifying an Exchange server. Google Sync must be sending a similar value for some reason.